# Why can't I use opening curly & square brackets on google cloud shell with macOS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I usually need to use opening curly & square brackets when I open GShell.

When using GShell on macOS, I can't use opening curly & square brackets. 
I guess the key combination is binded to something else on gshell.

Do I need to do something in my GShell to be able to do this ?

I've tested it on 3 differents mac to be sure I don't have a bad keybinding on mine.

Edit : I'm on AZERTY, it should have a link I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [keyboard layout support](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell#keyboard_layout_support) in order to be able to use special characters, and as you mention, the fact that you are using AZERTY is what most likely is causing a conflict between th keyboards.

Nevertheless, there is no way to completely change the layout of your keyboard in the Cloud Shell, but you can open a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under the 'Create new Cloud Shell issue' in order for GCP engineering to check if it is possible to add this option in the future.

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are often used, even have fixed meaning for most shells. So it is very strange that you "can' t use them". What, exactly, does that mean?

Comment: That means that when I try to tip those characters, they are not added into the prompt but something else is called on gshell